# Wifi connectivity issue during the installation of Freya

Tags: release-freya, wifi, networking, drivers, hardware

I wanted prove this linux distro (I heard good things about it), but I'm having this problem with the wifi connection: it simply doesn't work, both during installation and after i have installed the system.
More specifically, it finds my home connection, but it can't establish a connection, leaving me offline.
I have a USB WIFI ADAPTER, the specific model is the Atlantis Wireless N 300 mps NetFly UP WN (to be clear: http://www.atlantisland.it/pub/prodotti.php?famiglia=1&l1=2&l2=3&articolo=QTAyLVVQLVczMDBO).
In the manufacturer's webpage i found out the package with the driver (i believe), but I've not been able to install it (I have some knowledge of linux distros, but I'm not a dragon in this field...).

Can you suggest me some solution??

Oh, I was mforgetting: I don't have the possibility to connect my desktop pc directly to my mode-router directly with the ethernet wire...

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

That wifi adapter is based on Realtek 8192CU chipset,  with known bugs on Ubuntu and derivates.

If you can connect to inet from another pc, you must try to download a driver ported to kernel 3.13 and above, from the next address :

[Github.com pvaret](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)

Download the. zip file and copy it to a usb drive to paste in your elementary OS pc.

Once it will be in your pc, extract and rename the folder as **"realtek8192cu-fixes"**. Open panthon-files as root and paste this folder to **"/opt"**. Open *Readme.md* file inside the folder and follow the instructions.

If you need some aditional help, you can comment this answer.

**UPDATE:**

According to Readme.md file, I'll try to explain the installation steps:

- Open a terminal window or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> keys.
- Then you must execute: `sudo pantheon-files` and put your password when you ask for it. Now you have opened Files as root.
- Copy `rtl8192cu-fixes` folder to `/opt` folder.
- From `/opt` , click the right button mouse and choose `Open in ... Terminal` option. Now you can see a new terminal window prompted to `/opt` folder.
- Execute `sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes`.
- If an ***unknown command*** error appears, cause you haven't installed dkms , you can download to another computer the dkms trusty packages from: [Ubuntu trusty packages](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb). Copy to elementary OS pc and install it with the command: `sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb`. Try again with `sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes`.
- Execute `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10`.
- Execute `sudo depmod -a`.
- Once your new driver is installed , remove your old one from boot with `sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/`
- And finally you must disable power management executing `sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/8192cu-disable-power-management.conf /etc/modprobe.d/`.

Reboot your system and try to connect via wifi to your rooter.

Comment: I tried to do what you have suggested me, but I've encountered these problems (as i previously said, I'm not a dragon in these things): I have downloaded (by another pc) the zip from the site and renamed the extracted folder,but gave that the /opt folder didn't allow me to copy the files in, I searched online and i've found a solution to enable the operation (the command "sudo chmod -R 777 /opt"). From this point all has gone wrong and I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Comment: HI @OyD. I have edited my answer. I hope it help you.